# I need to get the text of the anchor tag and the link i.e. href of the anchor tag. I need to do the processing in php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

```
$strHTML = '<div>
<h2 class="entry-title">
<a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to BSR Fuels Report; Rezidor Hotels to Reduce Energy; Germany Caps Subsidies &ndash; 3BL Media Energy Minute" href="http://www.caelusgreenroom.com/2012/10/17/bsr-fuels-report-rezidor-hotels-to-reduce-energy-germany-caps-subsidies-3bl-media-energy-minute/">BSR Fuels Report; Rezidor Hotels to Reduce Energy; Germany Caps Subsidies &ndash; 3BL Media Energy Minute</a>
</h2>

<h2 class="entry-title">
<a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Small Business Healthcare Costs to Decrease; EU Pharma Guidelines &ndash; 3BL Media" href="http://www.caelusgreenroom.com/2012/10/17/small-business-healthcare-costs-to-decrease-eu-pharma-guidelines-3bl-media/">Small Business Healthcare Costs to Decrease; EU Pharma Guidelines &ndash; 3BL Media</a>
</h2>
</div>';
```

I have the above html as a string in a php variable as shown. I need to get the text of the anchor tag and the link i.e. href of the anchor tag. I need to do the processing in php. Can anyone please help?

Comment: [DOMdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) is all you need to know.

Comment: i used regular expressions. but it is not working.

Comment: [Regex is not an HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: I also used phpQuery. but dint find any code to get the href or innerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the String and then use [getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) function to retrieve all the `a` elements. Then you can just iterate over them using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and retrieve the data you want. Check out [DomElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) for a list of possible properties and methods.

Comment: In your case it would be `nodeValue`.